# Single-class vs two-classes hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, normal-distribution, model, mixture-distribution

Consider a Gaussian mixture model of unknown parameters, having just one or two components. I would like to design a statistical test to decide the number of classes ($H_0$: single component model vs. $H_1$: two components model).

I don't know how to formulate this. Can someone help me get started?

Comment: Seems similar to [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16677/finding-number-of-gaussians-in-a-finite-mixture-with-wilks-theorem). I have also seen the bootstrapped likelihood ratio test (BLRT) used by the folks over at MPLUS for this as well. More information on the BLRT can be found [here](http://www.statmodel.com/examples/webnotes/webnote14.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. The first one explains a technical difficulty related to a kind of degeneracy: H0 implies that the mixture model parameters are undeterminate. The second reference indeed provides further links to solutions such as the Lo-Mendell-Rubin test. Given the level of complexity of these approaches, I think I will consider a simple normality test (single component model vs arbitrary model).